# Sum multiple values under the same category

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to sum up the KWh produced during a given day. I have a table that shows how much KWh a solar farm produces hourly and I want to convert that table to daily. So in essence I am looking for a formula that will sum the KWh Produced each hour (as seen in column D) during a particular day.

[image: You will find the excel table here.]

As an example I would like to have a cell show the date "1/1/2021" and next to it the sum of the produced KWh, in the example that would be 30.32 KWh.

Comment: Did you try SUMIFS yet?

Comment: Or a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=SUMIF($A$10:$A$31,F10,$D$10:$D$31)

[image]